# How to hide menu 'Credit Memos' in sale order page, Magento 2

Tags: admin, orders, magento2.2, sales-order, menu

Using Magento 2.2, admin page. I need to hide menu **'Credit Memos'**  in order page of status **'Pending'**.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override xml in your extension of sales order view `vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml`

Remove below code from file: line 84 to 88

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Creditmemos" name="sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container"/>
<action method="addTab">
    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_creditmemos</argument>
    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container</argument>
</action>
```

Result : [Here](https://www.screencast.com/t/YhYZ1Wj80)

Answer (score 0):

Override Block of sales order view
`\vendor\magento\module-sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View.php`

Remove below code from file:

```
if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::creditmemo') && $order->canCreditmemo()) {
       $message = __(
           'This will create an offline refund. ' .
           'To create an online refund, open an invoice and create credit memo for it. Do you want to continue?'
       );
       $onClick = "setLocation('{$this->getCreditmemoUrl()}')";
       if ($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->isGateway()) {
           $onClick = "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->getCreditmemoUrl()}')";
       }
       $this->buttonList->add(
           'order_creditmemo',
           ['label' => __('Credit Memoss'), 'onclick' => $onClick, 'class' => 'credit-memo']
       );
   }
```

Comment: this work only for **Button** not for __Menu__.